# Save ios smiley in database mysql

Tags: mysql, ios

i have a small problem, in fact in one of my application, user can add a comment and if he activate the smiley keyBoard he can insert a smiley but in database it saved something like this ' ŸŽðŸ¶ðŸ‘', and in iphone it appear like this  , its normal :) but have you a solution to retrieve this smiley in my app ( encode ,decode .. ) ?

thank you .

Answer (score 4):

The characters you're describing here are from the [Emoji character set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji) of [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). Here's [the documentation you need,](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-unicode.html) along with a [tutorial](http://srinix.wordpress.com/2007/08/29/tutorial-how-to-store-utf8-indian-language-data-in-mysql/) for a related encoding problem.

Comment: Think for your answer, ill try it tomorrow, in office and give the structured solution.

Comment: i find a solution but i dont test it, in fact apple have changed the encoding type for Emoji in iO 5, and the solution seems to be simple, no need to modify your application, just modify the input and output type of the string, here's a link can help you to understand what you have to do :
 http://blog.manbolo.com/2011/12/12/supporting-ios-5-new-emoji-encoding.

@MrGomez thanks for help :)

Comment: @MalekRadhouani No problem. Happy to be of assistance!